# Dynamically esponsive attribute in knockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to knockoutJS and I really like it. My problem is that I can't figure out how to include some sort of validation in the binding. What I'm trying to do is to disable a button unless there is text in the text field.

```
<input type="text" name="answer" id="txtAnswer" placeholder="Answer..." data-bind="value: NewAnswer" />
<button data-inline="true" data-bind="click: addAnswer, enable: NewAnswer() != ''" >Add</button>
```

In my viewmodel I have 
     `self.NewAnswer = ko.observable($("#txtAnswer").val())`

I've tried everything I can think of, but can't make the button responsive. It seems to evaluate once, on page load, then nothing changes.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observable looks funky.  You don't need a jQuery selector inside of the call to `observable`.  You link the observable to an element via the `data-bind` attribute:

```
self.NewAnswer = ko.observable(''); //replace '' with any default value you want
```

Then your markup:

```
<input type="text" name="answer" id="txtAnswer" placeholder="Answer..." data-bind="value: NewAnswer" />
```

**Edit**

Here is a jsFiddle to demonstrate the working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/c6uts/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The way I wrote the observable was funky, but not really the reason it didn't work. Your jsFiddle demo helped me get the answer, though. In the end, it was something as silly as having my javascript libraries in the wrong order.